# How to say, "We are nearly there."

Tags: expressions, indications-de-lieu, formulation-idiomatique

What is the best way to say, "we are nearly there"? Is it correct to say, "Nous sommes y presque", or is, "nous sommes presque là", better, or?

Comment: Note that "Nous" is less and less used in spoken language. You may use "on" (used as "il", but meaning "nous") instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Nous y sommes presque” is correct, and it's idiomatic if the goal is an abstract one, i.e. when the sentence means “we've almost achieved our objective”. It isn't very idiomatic (possible, but not common) to express that a journey is almost over. For that, we'd say “nous sommes presque arrivés”.

“Nous sommes presque là” doesn't work. I can't really explain why; *là* is a pronoun that means a place that's somewhat distant, and it could fit in context, but the sentence just doesn't sound good. Instead you need to use the pronoun *y*. Normally *y* refers to a place that has already been mentioned, but in the sentence “nous y sommes (presque)”, it can stand for an implied goal even if that goal hasn't been mentioned explicitly.

In informal, spoken French, you can use “on y est presque” or “on est presque arrivés”.

Answer (score 4):

La forme la plus proche, et la plus employée est:

> Nous y sommes presque.

La forme suivante est équivalente, certes plus littérale, mais moins employée, car le pronom *y* est le plus souvent employé pour remplacer *là*:

> Nous sommes presque là.

Comment: Tu trouves "nous sommes presque là" plus littéral que "nous y sommes presque" ?

Comment: @Eria there = là, littéralement. "y" est une réduction. "Nous y sommes" = "nous sommes ici" également

Comment: Pour moi, "y" est un pronom, pas une réduction issue d'une déformation de la langue par habitude, tout comme "en" : "j'en ai parlé à mon collègue" à la place de "j'ai parlé de tel sujet à mon collègue". La forme utilisant le pronom est tout aussi "littérale" que celle qui ne l'utilise pas (même si je ne suis pas bien sûr du sens de "littéral" ici).

Comment: @Eria un pronom remplace un nom, et est donc réducteur: y se réfère à là, comme il pourrait signifier d'autres termes (amenés par le contexte précédent). Cela pourrait être: Nous sommes presque à la fin. Dans la version anglaise, pas de pronom, there est auto-suffisant.

Answer (score 3):

What is the best way to say, "we are nearly there"? Is it correct to say, "New sommes y presque", or is, "nous sommes presque là", better, or?

As Guillaume pointed in his answer, one way to say it would be

> Nous y sommes presque. / Nous sommes presque là.

If your sentence's context contain some temporal event, you could also say something like :

> Nous y sommes bientôt. / Nous sommes bientôt là.

Another way to say it, would be using the 'on' pronoun.
If the context allows it, you could even say something like :

> On arrive !

Comment: The shorter the better, imo! In the contexts where I most often needed to convey this information to my annoying children in the car, even just “Bientôt!” or “Presque!” all by themselves were adequate to respond to their incessant inquiries: “Papa, on arrive bientôt?”/ “Papa, on est arrivés?”  (c’est même possible que j’ai répondu des fois avec “Vos gueules” quand j’avais l’impression qu’ils se foutaient de la mienne à l'unisson!) +1

Answer (score 3):

Quasiment plus personne ne dit « Nous y sommes presque » en dehors de contextes formels. Dans l'écrasante majorité des cas, *We are almost there* se traduit à l'oral par :

> On y est presque. (un objectif)

ou

> On est presque arrivés. (un trajet)

---

Almost nobody say *Nous y sommes presque* these days, outside formal contexts. In most cases, "We are almost there" can be translated in spoken French by:

> On y est presque. (a goal)

or

> On est presque arrivés. (a trip)

---

Note: *Nous* is essentially used by foreign people learning French these days. While French people are often eager to correct foreigners trying to speak French, they are never taught about this specific usage as it is not technically a mistake.